# Stored Procedures executing twice!

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

For some reason my stored procedures are all executing twice! I have a static function that runs an SP given its name and the parameters and fills a datatable.

```
Public Shared Function RunSP(ByVal spName As String, ByRef spParams As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByRef pDataTable As DataTable) As Integer
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim lAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = spName

        For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In spParams
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value)
        Next

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Not pDataTable Is Nothing Then
            lAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            lAdapter.Fill(pDataTable)
        End If
        RunSP = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        If (Not cmd Is Nothing) Then
            cmd.Dispose()
        End If
        RunSP = -1
    End Try
End Function
```

Is there something wrong with the code? I've checked with the debugger and the appropriate SPs are definitely only being called once, i.e. this function only runs once for a particular insertion function, but two things are inserted into the table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are executing it once manually (`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`), then the adapter will execute it once (`New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)... Fill(...)`). Thus twice. Did you mean to use a different command for the adapter?

Comment: I want to get a DataTable back, is there a way that won't execute the query again, or should I scrap the "ExecuteNonQuery" part?

Comment: Scrap the ExecuteNonQuery part. That's usually for running code that doesn't return rows, such as updates and deletes.

Answer (score 6):

You're running the stored procedure twice, one in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery and then a second time when you're running lAdapter.Fill.